# How can options be parsed in a Bash script, leaving unrecognized options after the "--"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I'm looking for a way to do option parsing in a Bash script (allowing for both short and long arguments as **getopt** does) that stops parsing at the first unrecognized argument, places a **--** before that first unrecognized argument, and then copies the remaining arguments to the output string.

For example, here's the behavior that I want:

```
% OPTIONS=("-u" "name1" "--username=name2" "-x" "a" -u "b" "c")
% getopt -o u: -l username: -n programname -- "${OPTIONS[@]}"
-u 'name1' --username 'name2' -- -x 'a' -u 'b' 'c'
%
```

The utility getopt does not work this way, and instead emits the following:

```
programname: invalid option -- 'x'
-u 'name1' --username 'name2' -u 'b' -- 'a' 'c'
```

Note that I do not want arguments that follow an unrecognized option to be reordered as if they were recognized, as is demonstrated above with the second **-u** option. I'm hoping that someone will have a solution that will give the results I demonstrate in the first code block above.  Any ideas?

**Environment:** bash 4.2.46(1), CentOS 7.2 @3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64.

**Requirements:** CentOS 7.2 Minimal with no additional software to be installed with all code written in a Bash script. The options passed to the options parser are not required to include **--** in them (that is, the termination of parsing should be automatic).

Comment: can you check this post answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options

Comment: In the answer provided by Arvid Requate and edited by TomRoche, there is an initial colon in the optspec.  What does that do?  Also, I like the "trick" of including -: in the optspec. Is there a way to modify the code so that one would not have to duplicate code for both short and long options?

Comment: Ah, leading colon turns on silent error reporting

Comment: Should this also work for invalid long options?

Comment: Yes, invalid long options should also terminate parsing.  For example, the options `-u name1 --unknown -u name2 --username name3` should result in the string: `-u 'name1' -- --unknown -u 'name2' --username 'name3'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem requires something other than **getopt** because **getopt** rearranges options that it finds that do match the option specification and terminates on unrecognized options. The Bash built-in **getopts** comes to the rescue, but needs to be able to handle long options. In a post by [Arvid Requate and TomRoche](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options), there is a "trick" that allows **getopts** to handle long options: use **-** as an option specification and use a leading colon in the options specification to silence error reporting. Their solution, however, would require that code be duplicated for handling short and long options.

Here is a solution that I've tested that meets all of my requirements and also does not duplicate handling for short and long options. For clarity and completeness, I've changed **username** to **set** and added **toggle** to demonstrate options not taking values.

**parse.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

Options=("$@")
while getopts ":s:-:" OptChar "${Options[@]}"; do
   case "$OptChar" in
    -)   case "$OPTARG" in
         set|set=*)
            if [[ $OPTARG =~ ^set= ]] ; then
               Value="${Options[$OPTIND-2]#*=}"
            else
               Value="${Options[$OPTIND-1]}"
               ((OPTIND++))
            fi
            echo "Parsed: --$OPTARG, value: '$Value'"
            ;;

         toggle)
            echo "Parsed: --$OPTARG";;
         *) ((OPTIND--)); break;;
         esac
         ;;

   # Redirect short arguments to long arguments
   s)    ((OPTIND-=2)); Options[OPTIND-1]="--set";;
   t)    ((OPTIND--)); Options[OPTIND-1]="--toggle";;

   *)    ((OPTIND--)); break;;
   esac
done
Options=( "${Options[@]:$OPTIND-1}" )

echo "REMAINING Options: ${Options[@]}"
```

and here is my test code:

```
% ./parse.sh --set=a  -s b --set= --set c --unknown -s d --set e
Parsed: --set=a, value: 'a'
Parsed: --set, value: 'b'
Parsed: --set=, value: ''
Parsed: --set, value: 'c'
REMAINING Options: --unknown -s d --set e
%
% ./parse.sh -s a -x -s b
Parsed: --set, value: 'a'
REMAINING Options: -x -s b
%
```

Comment: Have you tested the short options?  `./parse.sh -x` does not work for me.

Comment: @rudimeier Thanks... I've added the fix for the short options.  The * case at the outer layer needed `((OPTIND--))`.

Answer (score 0):

This may work if you don't use combined short options like "-ax":

```
OPTIONS=("-u" "name1" "--username=name2" "-x" "a" -u "b" "c")

for i in `seq ${#OPTIONS[@]} -1 0`; do
  OFIRST=("${OPTIONS[@]:0:$i}")
  getopt -o u: -l username: -n programname -- "${OFIRST[@]}" &>/dev/null && break
done

NEWOPT=("${OPTIONS[@]:0:$i}" "--"  "${OPTIONS[@]:$i}")

getopt -o u: -l username: -n programname -- "${NEWOPT[@]}"
```

I'm sure that there are issues with this solution. Probably you would better try to add this feature to getopt.c source code from util-linux.

Comment: Thank you rudimeier for your participation in this discussion. I looked at your solution, but instead chose to do the one I've added as an answer to the question. Folks like you make this place great.